# Selecting a nested stdClass Object

Tags: php, json

Hi I was wondering if it is possible to grab:

Here is my current code:

```
    <?php
         include('php-riot-api.php');
         $region = 'euw';
         $grab_id = 19631093;
         $instance = new riotapi($region);
         $grab_dataB = $instance->getStats($grab_id);
         $decode_dataB = json_decode($grab_dataB);
         $grab_tier = $decode_data->{'aggregatedStats[7].Unranked[wins]'};

         print_r($decode_dataB);
?>
```

This is my result:
http://2v2.lolnode.com/testing.php (http://pastebin.com/DrJDnuaC)

I would like to be able to get the numbered result for Unranked[wins] (which is  `[aggregatedStats] => stdClass Object ( )` ) [7])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get directly:

```
$grab_tier = $decode_dataB->playerStatSummaries[7]->wins;
```

But you won't know for sure that the 8'th key is the one you want, or ...

You can loop in your results:

```
$unranked = '';
foreach($decode_dataB->playerStatSummaries as $summary){
    if($summary->playerStatSummaryType == 'Unranked'){
        $unranked = $summary;
        break;
    }
}

print_r($unranked);
```

and get values, eg `$unranked->wins`

you can [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/json_decode) with 2'nd parameter `true` (object is transformed into array) and loop like a normal array.

```
$decode_dataB = json_decode($grab_dataB, true);
```

Comment: Hi, I am using your `foreach()` code, and it seems that some people get an error going to the page where it is used, why might this be?

Comment: I have now updated for `$decode_dataB = json_decode($grab_dataB, true);` and now I am getting an error too.